# how to create multiple Concatenation on multiple left joins in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to left join table HE to table S as shown in the code below.

In order for me to get a match and join in the data, i have to concat client id and market as shown below in [Headendmarket&tbcode] and [SETClientID+Market] from both S and HE tables.

but because some of the data in the columns are not clean. the concat above is not enough and there are some missing things coming in S in the join.

the solution for me would be to further vlook up the data for the data that is left null after running the query below and do another concat on S.[Market]&s.[client] and leftjoin it further with HE.[HeadendMarket] & [HE.Advertisername]. this is going to match the remaining data thats null to see if there is a possible match and bring back the data it can for the S table.

not sure what is the best way for me to do this in this query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(HE.[AdvertiserTBCode],HE.[HeadendMarket]) AS [Headendmarket&tbcode]
      ,CONCAT(S.[CLIENTID],S.[Market]) AS [SETClientID+Market]
      ,HE.[CurrentRegionName]
      ,HE.[CurrentMarketName]
      ,HE.[CurrentSalesTeamName]
      ,HE.[CurrentSalesOfficeName]
      ,HE.[CurrentCorpAEName]
      ,HE.[CurrentAEType]
      ,HE.[AdvertiserTBCode]  --Has all the correct data--
      ,HE.[AdvertiserName]
      ,HE.[ParentAdvertiserName]
      ,HE.[HeadendRegion]
      ,HE.[HeadendMarket]  --has all correct data--
      ,HE.[CorpCategoryGroup]
      ,S.[Actuals vs projections]
      ,S.[Year]
      ,S.[Month]
      ,S.[Area]
      ,CASE S.[Market] --some markets not the same name which is why we are doing this to have the same markets as HE Table--
            WHEN 'Twin Cities' THEN 'Minneapolis - St. Paul'
            WHEN 'Fort Myers'  THEN 'Ft. Myers - Naples'
            WHEN 'Bowling Green' THEN 'Nashville'
            WHEN 'North Miss' THEN 'TUPELO'
            WHEN 'Monroe, LA' THEN 'Monroe' 
            WHEN 'Southern Miss-Hattiesburg/Laurel/Meridian' THEN 'SOUTHERN MISS'
            WHEN 'Northern Miss-Columbus/Tupelo' THEN 'Tulepo'
            WHEN 'Little Rock, AR' THEN 'Little Rock'
            WHEN 'Fort Wayne' THEN 'Ft. Wayne'
            WHEN 'Wheeling/Youngstown/Canfield' THEN 'WYC'
            WHEN 'Johnstown/Altoona/State College' THEN 'Johnstown-Altoona'
            WHEN 'Washington, D.C.' THEN 'Washington'
        ELSE S.[Market] END AS [SET Market]

      ,S.[Zone Type]
      ,S.[Category]
      ,S.[Subcategory]
      ,S.[Event]
      ,S.[Network]
      ,S.[AE]
      ,S.[Client]  -- some wrong fields--
      ,S.[ClientID] --some incorrect data entered. this with the market concatenation should match the data in the HE table in a perfect world.--
      ,S.[# Spots]
      ,S.[Gross ($)]


  FROM [REO].[dbo].[Sports] S
  LEFT JOIN [REO].[dbo].[HF_Final] HE

        ON CONCAT(S.[CLIENTID],CASE S.[Market]
            WHEN 'Twin Cities' THEN 'Minneapolis - St. Paul'
            WHEN 'Fort Myers'  THEN 'Ft. Myers - Naples'
            WHEN 'Bowling Green' THEN 'Nashville'
            WHEN 'North Miss' THEN 'TUPELO'
            WHEN 'Monroe, LA' THEN 'Monroe' 
            WHEN 'Southern Miss-Hattiesburg/Laurel/Meridian' THEN 'SOUTHERN MISS'
            WHEN 'Northern Miss-Columbus/Tupelo' THEN 'Tulepo'
            WHEN 'Little Rock, AR' THEN 'Little Rock'
            WHEN 'Fort Wayne' THEN 'Ft. Wayne'
            WHEN 'Wheeling/Youngstown/Canfield' THEN 'WYC'
            WHEN 'Johnstown/Altoona/State College' THEN 'Johnstown-Altoona'
            WHEN 'Washington, D.C.' THEN 'Washington'
            ELSE S.[Market] END) 
            = CONCAT(HE.[AdvertiserTBCode],HE.[HeadendMarket])
```

Comment: Update your question with sample data, please.  See [ask] and [mcve] for additional details.

Answer (score 0):

Please identify ALL Table&Column(s) that do not have "Clean Data".
And give examples--eg Bad=;ShouldBe=.  These columns may affect how we proceed.  And, get rid of the extraneous columns that are not part of the problem.

In the meantime, you can identify the exact dirty data and add some more conditioning...  Note: this sql will allow you to see nulls on either side of the ON condition.  That is, some HE data may not match because the S data is incorrect.

```
SELECT
    AllKeys.AdvertiserTBCode
    ,AllKeys.Market

    ,S.AdvertiserTBCode
    .S.Market

    ,HE.CLIENTID
    .HE.Market

From
-- get all of the possible keys from each side
(SELECT DISTINCT
    ,AdvertiserTBCode
    ,Market   -- or CASE Market...
 FROM [REO].[dbo].[Sports]

UNION

SELECT
    CLIENTID
    ,Market   -- or CASE Market...
FROM [REO].[dbo].[HF_Final] 
) as AllKeys

-- join each side to its keys
LEFT JOIN [REO].[dbo].[Sports] S
  ON  AllKeys.AdvertiserTBCode = S.AdvertiserTBCode
  And AllKeys.Market = S.Market

LEFT JOIN [REO].[dbo].[HF_Final] HE
  ON  AllKeys.AdvertiserTBCode = HE.CLIENTID
  And AllKeys.Market = HE.Market

Order By AllKeys.AdvertiserTBCode, AllKeys.Market

-- now filter those that you want to pay attention to
--Having maybe some nulls in certain fields
```

Comment: hi i have added field that has the dirty data. basically  anything in the he table has clean data. and the S.[ClientID] and has incorrect data entered but has the best match with the HE table data. the S.[Client]  has incorrect info as people enter the client names wrong so not as reliable as cliend id . this with the s.market concatenation should match the data in the HE table combo in a perfect world. but unfortunately since some of the ids are entered incorrectly in S.[ClientID]. we have to mix and match other fields for what is shown as null.so the s.client is the best possible match.